# VSCode WebViewPanel behind corporate proxy

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, networking, http-proxy

I am using the "C4 DSL Extension" of VSCode to show previews of my architecture diagrams. The previews are rendered through the WebviewPanel. The source code can be found here: https://gitlab.com/systemticks/c4-grammar/-/blob/master/extension/src/c4-structurizr-preview.ts

It works through a direct connection, but once connected with my corporate network, all requests have to pass through a proxy. VSCode itself handles proxies through the http_proxy and https_proxy variables. However, the WebviewPanel does not seem to take those settings.

The following figure shows an excerpt of the console. You can see, that the request to query the "structurizr-embed.js" failed.
[image]

Is this behavior intended? I could not find a setting in VSCode to enable WebviewPanel to request via proxy.

Note: I am using the Linux version of VSCode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by setting the `http.proxy` variable in VSCode. We are using authentication for proxies and previously I exported the `http_proxy` environment variable in the form of `http_proxy=http://<username>:<password>@<host>:<port>`.

However, VSCode expects this variable without credentials: `http_proxy=http://<host>:<port>`. Now I don't understand where it talks the credentials from, but it works.